# Infinite [Bad instruction address] occurred and ignored error occurs. What can be changed to fix this problem?

Tags: mips, fibonacci

I am working on a MIPS Fibonacci sequence. However, if I run the program, I input a number and all I get is infinite number of the error: **[Bad instruction address]**  occurred and ignored infinite times. What should I do? And I am only allowed to change the code between the ##########s.

Below is my MIPS code.

```
.data

newline:
  .asciiz "\n"

str0:
  .asciiz "Enter a positive integer: "

str1:
  .asciiz "ERROR: received a negative integer!\n"

str2:
  .asciiz "INFO: fibonacci returned "

.text

# $a0: n (<1024)
################################################################################FIXME

fibonacci:
  
  li $t2, 1
  addiu $sp, $sp, -12
  sw $ra, 0($sp)
  sw $s0, 4($sp)
  sw $s1, 8($sp)

  addiu $s0, $a0, 0
  beq $zero, $s0, ResultOne
  beq $t2, $s0, ResultOne
  bltz $s0, Negative

  addiu $a0, $s0, -1
  jal fibonacci
  addiu $s1, $v1, 0
  addiu $a0, $s0, -2
  jal fibonacci
  addu $v1, $v1, $s1
  j finish

ResultOne:
  
  li $v0, 1
  li $v1, 1
  j Finish

Negative:

  li $v0, 0
  j Finish

Finish:
  
  lw $s1, 8($sp)
  lw $s0, 4($sp)
  lw $ra, 0($ra)
  addiu $sp, $sp,12
  jr $ra

# FIXME
################################################################################

.globl main
main:

  # print_string str0
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, str0
  syscall

  # $t0 = read_int
  li $v0, 5
  syscall
  move $t0, $v0

  # $s0 = $ra; fibonacci($t0); $ra = $s0
  move $s0, $ra
  move $a0, $t0
  jal fibonacci
  move $ra, $s0

  # $t0 = $v0; $t1 = $v1
  move $t0, $v0
  move $t1, $v1

  # if ($t0 == 0) { goto main_failure }
  beq $t0, $zero, main_failure

main_success:

  # print_string str2
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, str2
  syscall

  # print_int $t1
  li $v0, 1
  move $a0, $t1
  syscall

  # print_string newline
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, newline
  syscall

  # goto main_return
  b main_return

main_failure:

  # print_string str1
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, str1
  syscall

main_return:

  # return
  jr $ra
```

Comment: 1. What is the actual, complete error message?  2. Are you using SPIM or MARS?

Comment: I am using SPIM. Sorry I forgot to mention that. The exact error message is as follows.

Comment: Exception occurred at PC=0x00115798
  Bad address in text read: 0x00115798
  Exception 6  [Bad instruction address]  occurred and ignored
Exception occurred at PC=0x0011579c
  Bad address in text read: 0x0011579c
  Exception 6  [Bad instruction address]  occurred and ignored
Exception occurred at PC=0x001157a0
  Bad address in text read: 0x001157a0
  Exception 6  [Bad instruction address]  occurred and ignored

Comment: And I just get infinite number of these kind of errors... and I have no idea why!

Comment: Your program is sending the processor to invalid memory for instructions.  To see why your program is doing that, single step until either you get the error.  The actual  instruction (of your program) that sent it into the weeds will be with a PC whose value is something like 00400xxx.  You'll then need to examine that instruction and perhaps look at conditions surrounding its execution.

Comment: The debugging process can work in two directions.  Forward debugging: single step validating that, after each instruction, all registers and memory meet your expectations.  Backward debugging: find an error and work backward one instruction to see why the error occurred.  Sometimes that one instruction is the offending one, and other times, it is correct but received bad data from a prior instruction, so go back more to find the cause of the bad data.

Comment: I generally prefer forward debugging, since you can find the first error first and don't have to think about how instructions mis-performed given bad data from eariler bugs.

Comment: Errors can come from any number of sources.  Often, they are simple typo's, where the idea is correct but wrong register used somewhere.  Other times, there are more serious logic error rather than typos..

Comment: Thanks Erik, after you commented, I tried forward debugging and now it works. The problem was just a typo like you mentioned. Thanks for your detailed answers!